# Why does using .decode() consume both instances of a file? Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am retrieving a CSV file from an html form and decoding it with utf-8. I need two instances of this file in my program for various reasons but when I use .decode('utf-8') both instances of the file are consumed by the .decode() function.

Python code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            #get the uploaded file
            file = request.files['file']
            file_copy = file
            bank_selection = request.form['banks']

            line_num = banks.get_line_no(file_copy)
```

*for some reason the .decode() function in get_line_no consumes file and file_copy*

```
def get_line_no(file):

        file_data = file.read().decode('utf-8')

        for line_num, row in enumerate(file_data.split('\n')):
            if ',' in row and row.split(',')[0] == 'Date':
                break
        print(line_num)

        return line_num
```

For some reason this does not work because when I try

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=(line_num))
```

pandas returns an empty error because both the original file and file_copy have been consumed by .decode()

The only way I've gotten it to work is by getting the user to send two files in the html form and retrieve them into different variables:

```
file = request.files['file']
file_copy = request.files['file2']
```

Why is this happening?
Is there maybe a way to send two copies of the file from the html without the user having to input it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_copy = file` doesn't create a new copy of the file or file handle, it just assigns the existing file handle referred to by `file` to `file_copy`. Once you read the file pointed to by `file` using `file.read()`, that also reads the file pointed to by `file_copy`, since it's the same handle. Instead, just create a copy of the file *data*, e.g.:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #get the uploaded file
    file = request.files['file']
    file_data = file.read()
    bank_selection = request.form['banks']

    line_num = get_line_no(file_data)
    # after the function returns, file_data will still be availabe (and undecoded)

def get_line_no(file_data):
    decoded = file_data.decode('utf-8')

    for line_num, row in enumerate(file_data.split('\n')):
        if ',' in row and row.split(',')[0] == 'Date':
            break
    print(line_num)

    return line_num
```

If you need to read the same file with `.read_csv()`, you can create a `StringIO` object to allow it to be read as a file:

```
from io import StringIO

dataframe = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_data.decode()), skiprows=(line_num))
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this still isn't working with pandas as .read() is consuming the original file and pandas won't interpret a 'bytes' type object, so it won't use file_data or file. I need 'file' to be preserved in its unread and original form.

Comment: I don't think you understand sufficiently how reading a file works. What do you mean by "I need 'file' to be preserved in its unread and original form."? In this answer, `file_data` contains the contents of `file` - rereading them would change nothing. If you have trouble passing the content to `pandas`, it would make sense to include that in your question right away - you could simply decode the data again, or just keep a reference to the decoded data instead.

Comment: Well when I pass file_data into pandas.read_csv(file_data) it returns an error where it can't use file_data because it is of type 'bytes'. Meaning that performing the .read() function converted 'file' into bytes form as well as in 'file_data' which pandas cannot handle. By 'original form' I meant before the .read() function took place. Sorry for not being clear initially. tl;dr I need two copies of the file, one read and decoded one not.

Comment: All files are of type `bytes`, unless you instruct Python to interpret those bytes as text (which means you want Python to either decide on a decoding, or you tell it decode it using a specific decoding). Apparently, what you get back from `request.files['file']` is undecoded, in bytes - if `pandas.read_csv()` doesn't accept a binary file (i.e. bytes), you can just do what I shared above, pass the decoded contents using `StringIO`.